# Precognitive Badge on Meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

According to the [Badge List](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/badges) one can be awarded the [Precognitive](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/66/precognitive) badge here on Meta, as well as on the Main site.

Given that no-one has been awarded it (whereas all eligible recipients will have it on main, already), I suspect it's inclusion on the List is in error?

Not remotely important to fix... but just the Test Engineer in me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precognitive is advertised on all sites (which includes meta sites) to help raise awareness of the Area 51 process, that's all.

It's even on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/badges), which not only didn't have a proposal but predates the whole idea of Area 51 and Stack Exchange 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for an "official" response Kevin. If that is the intent, then so-be-it but it seems a bit illogical to me!?

Answer (score 3):

The badge list for Precognitive says "Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase".

"This site" is meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com.  There wasn't an Area 51 proposal for it, so it can't issue that badge.

"This site" was created automatically as a result of a different site being created (genealogy.stackexchange.com).  THAT site did have an Area 51 proposal, so does have the badge.

That's the way I read it, at least.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why they'd bother awarding the badge on Meta or what it means.

Going to another Beta site, e.g. Personal Finance and Money, I see it has awarded Precognitive [on its main site 65 times](https://money.stackexchange.com/badges/62/precognitive) but [on its Meta site zero times](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/61/precognitive).

However, I did not get the badge, because I accidentally hit "Unfollow" on Sep 10 and then hit "Follow" again right after to undo that. As a result, I was recorded as following one day after the Committment phase started.

So it is with badges.

Comment: The whole "Badges on Meta" issue is a separate can of worms... but if SE are going to do it, they should do it right....

Comment: I think they should have a special badge for you, Multicognitive - you recruited so many new members!  It's very very ironic you didn't get Precognitive

Comment: @Jeni - well I did get the Activist gold badge at Area 51 when I snuck in with my 100th referral just prior to the end of the Committment phase, when I thinking I'd miss it by a couple.